# What would std::cout before calling my function do in this case?

Tags: c++

```cpp
#include <iostream>
    
// **Change needs_it_support so that it returns support:**
bool needs_it_support() {
      
    bool support;
      
    std::cout << "Hello. IT. Have you tried turning it off and on again? Enter 1 for yes, 0 for no.\n";
    std::cin >> support;
    return support;
}
    
int main() {
      
    // **Change the following line to print the function result:**
    needs_it_support();  
      
}
```

I understand that to make this work the way I want to, I would have to do:

```
std::cout << (call my function)
```

But, my question is, what does that do? Wouldn't that just execute all my code and try to output it to the console, and then obviously give me errors? Or, does it only output specific things?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. std::cout will print the result returned from your function. What errors are you referring too?

Comment: well if i std::cout << and then call the function here, wouldn't that try to output all the code I just called? or how does that work? i just dont understand what calling it after saying std::cout does will it only print the returned value?

Comment: Write a simple program and try it . You will get your answer.

Answer (score 1):

```cpp
std::cout << needs_it_support()
```

This will call `needs_it_support()` first, and then pass its `bool` return value to `operator<<`.  It is essentially calling:

```cpp
std::cout.operator<<(needs_it_support())
```

So, whatever `bool` value `needs_it_support()` returns, that is what will be printed to the console (in addition to anything else that `needs_it_support()` itself prints internally).